# Azure Application Gateway backend hostname matching errors

Tags: azure

Application gateway gives me an error:

'Backend health': 'The Common Name (CN) of the backend certificate does not match the host header of the probe.' for both backend instances.

But if I try to access scale set instances directly, the certificate is valid:

https://apitestss000000.mycorp.local/
and
https://apitestss000001.mycorp.local/

look fine and valid in browser

HTTP setting is set to 'Pick hostname from backend target.' If I set it to 'Override with specific domain name' and type in one of the hostnames like 'apitestss000001.mycorp.local', there is no error for this host, but still error for the other. Looks like 'Pick hostname from backend target' picks the wrong hostname from the scale set.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you self-signed your certificates.  That will be problematic for anything not on your domain/using your Enterprise CA and PKI setup, which includes Azure health probes.  You'll either need to upload the public root cert in the Azure portal, or get certificates signed by a 3rd party CA that Microsoft probes trust.

Comment: Public root cert of our CA is uploaded to "HTTP settings".

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue where I only updated the certificate on the WAG and when the cert expired I got this error. Then I researched and found that when cert update is needed it needs to be updated in the WAG as well as the web servers. Same cert updated in the web servers, problem resolved.